# OrientDB ETL,how to import edges with attributes in Json file

Tags: json, etl, orientdb

I have 2 json source files, entities.json & relations.json:

[entities.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnsS9.png)

[relations.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh4vE.png)

and ,this is my json script：

[node.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brbtt.png)

[edges.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIYBD.png)

I can import vertices successful, but edges has problems.

How can I import edges with attributes in Json file by OrientDB ETL?

Comment: Hi, have you took a llok at this? https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Transformer.html#edge-transformer Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for help.I use COMMOND(create EDGE relation from * to *) in transformers,it works well when import csv source file, but when I import json source file ,it doesn't.Have you used this before?